# Kotlin coroutines repeated test_run forces method calls out of order

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I wrote code that is supposed to execute sequnce of orders on device, and in my infinite wisdom, i decided to learn coroutines and do it with them. I wrote tests, i wrote code, and everything seemed to run. But then i tryed to run the test multiple times and it started to fail.
Even when i run signle test on repeat, it works about 10 times, then fails 10 times, works 10 again and then continues to fail. Or works 7 times, then fails.
Sometimes all 30 runs pass, sometimes they start failing from 5-7th repeat.

[image: picture 1 - repeat test that works, fails, works and fails]

At this point, i am not entirely sure what is happening so i would like to ask for help and clarification. I will try to provide all relevant code in code snippets.

Test Code:

```
@RepeatedTest(30)
        fun id_7_doubleDelayedScenarioStepTest() = runBlocking {
            val testId = "ID_7"
            //Init - reates scenario template of calls
            val inputTemplateId = scenarioService.createTemplate(
                ScenarioTemplateDto(0, "delayTestScenario", 11, null, testUtils.prepareDoubleDelaySteps(testId), false)
            ).id

            //Mock
            coEvery { publisher.publishChangeState(any()) } returns Unit
            mockkStatic(LocalDateTime::class)
            coEvery { LocalDateTime.now() } returns LocalDateTime.MAX

            //Expected output
            val expectedRequestFirstStep = testUtils.generateOneTimeReq(testId, 1)
            val expectedDelayStart = testUtils.generateIncomingRequest(testId, 2)
            val expectedDelayEnd = testUtils.generateLastRequest(testId, 3)
            val expectedRequestMiddleStep = testUtils.generateOneTimeReq(testId, 4)
            val expectedDelayStart2 = testUtils.generateIncomingRequest(testId, 5)
            val expectedDelayEnd2 = testUtils.generateLastRequest(testId, 6)
            val expectedRequestLastStep = testUtils.generateOneTimeReq(testId, 7)

            //Execution
            scenarioService.startScenario(inputTemplateId)

            delay(2200) //wait for coroutine to finnish in background

            //Validation
            coVerifySequence {
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedRequestFirstStep)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedDelayStart)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedDelayEnd)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedRequestMiddleStep)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedDelayStart2)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedDelayEnd2)
                publisher.publishChangeState(expectedRequestLastStep)
            }
            coVerify(exactly = 7) { publisher.publishChangeState(any()) }
        }
```

**Production code:**

Coroutine launch in listener:

```
coroutineScope.launch { scenarioExecuteService.processInstance(scenario) }
```

Scenario execution:

```
//function to process scenario
 private suspend fun processStepsWithoutInit(steps: MutableList<Step>, instance: Scenario) {
        steps.forEach { step ->
            when (step) {
                is CommandStep -> processCommandStep(step, instance)
                is DelayedStep -> processDelayedStep(step, instance)
                is ToggledStep -> processToggledStep(step, instance)
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown step type: $step.")
            }
        }
        removeLiveInstance(instance.templateId)
    }
//process command step
private fun processCommandStep(step: CommandStep, instance: Scenario) {
        changeStateProduction.sendChangeState(
            step.priority, instance.id, step.commands.map { it.toDto() }, ONE_TIME_REQ
        )
    }

//process delay step
private suspend fun processDelayedStep(step: DelayedStep, instance: Scenario) {
        changeStateProduction.sendChangeState(
            step.priority, instance.id, step.startCommands.map { it.toDto() }, INCOMING_REQ
        )
        executeDelay(step, instance)
    }

private suspend fun executeDelay(step: DelayedStep, instance: Scenario) {
        addStoppedInstance(instance, step, coroutineContext[Job]!!)

        delay(step.delay * MILLIS_TO_SECONDS)

        removeStoppedInstance(instance.templateId)
        changeStateProduction.sendChangeState(
            step.priority, instance.id, step.endCommands.map { it.toDto() }, LAST_REQ
        )
    }
```

Publisher call from another class:

```
override fun sendChangeState(
        priority: Long,
        scenarioId: Long,
        commandDto: List<CommandDto>,
        incomingRequest: ChangeStateIncomingRequest
    ) {
        publisher.publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority, scenarioId, commandDto, incomingRequest, LocalDateTime.now()))
    }
```

**Edit**:publisher.publishChangeState(), where topic identifier is just kafka topic

```
fun publishChangeState(dto: ChangeStateDto){
        kafkaSender.sendAsync(ChangeStateTopicIdentifier, dto)
    }
```

Relevant part of assertion error for failed tests:
Note that steps should be in order.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: calls are not exactly matching verification sequence
Matchers:
+ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
+ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
+ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
+ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
+ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
Calls:
1) +ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
2) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
3) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
4) +ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
5) +ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
6) +ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
7) +ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))
```

Logs without mocked time, shows correct order of calls:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: calls are not exactly matching verification sequence

Matchers: 
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))

Calls:
1) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:47:59.801667033))
2) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:47:59.804052947))
3) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:00.810543824))
4) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:00.810967145))
5) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:00.811149370))
6) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:01.811669793))
7) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:01.812102842))
```

Logs without mocked time, shows out of order calls:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: calls are not exactly matching verification sequence

Matchers: 
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))
ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(eq(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999))))

Calls:
1) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step1, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:20.569352998))
2) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step4, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:20.569715183))
3) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step7, params={})], incomingRequest=ONE_TIME_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:20.569895464))
4) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step2, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:20.570100752))
5) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step3, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:21.570680136))
6) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step5, params={})], incomingRequest=INCOMING_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:21.571068331))
7) ObjectPublisher(objectPublisher bean#1).publishChangeState(ChangeStateDto(priority=1, scenarioId=0, commandDto=[CommandDto(deviceId=1, key=ID_7_step6, params={})], incomingRequest=LAST_REQ, timestamp=2023-09-22T14:48:22.571620073))
```

I will be honest, i have no idea what causes this problem.
I tryed to run my code in debug, but i did not encounter this error once.
I tryed to exchange forEach for while(steps.isNotEmpty){step = steps[0], steps.remove(step), when (step)...} and even run different parts of code in RunBlocking, but nothing seems to affect this particullar error.

Is it possible that this is caused by spring caching, code optimalization or my mistake in using coroutines? As in, they cannot be used in the way i try to do?

**Edit2:**
Unsure if relevant or even a side effect, but when I tried to print additional information about coroutine that calls `publisher.publishStateChange`, I encountered interesting indexing.

When test finishes successfully, coroutine index increases by 10, when it fails, it increases only by 8.

**Success run:**
[image: run1]
next:
[image: run2]

**Fail run:**
[image: run8]
next:
[image: run9]

this indexing is consistent even if tests start to pass again, where it switches back to 10 increment.

**Edit 3:**
In retrospect it seems stupid that i did not catch this earlier, but i tried printing list of steps. And sometimes, it is ordered. I imagine this may be the main problem, not the coroutines. Still no idea why this happens, but probably better place to look for error.

example of correct output:

```
scenario.CommandStep@1e180d26,
scenario.DelayedStep@22419bfe,
scenario.CommandStep@7f252347,
scenario.DelayedStep@6948e3df,
scenario.CommandStep@3767b2ed
```

example of fail output:

```
scenario.CommandStep@2aea33e7, 
scenario.CommandStep@5b1b5947, 
scenario.CommandStep@24f290de, 
scenario.DelayedStep@19f632b6, 
scenario.DelayedStep@62784f64]
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `publisher.publishChangeState()`? This looks like some kind of race condition, suggesting an incorrectly defined suspend function. (just one possibility) Not sure I can help further because I know zero about Spring.

Comment: Edit added, but I do not know how that would make this error, but I do not know many things. If I understand mocking properly, we never even get to this code.

Comment: That explains it. That function is asynchronous—it’s even in the name. That means it starts its work on some other thread without waiting for it to finish. So  your code has nothing in it that would enforce a certain order of events. If you want it to be synchronous so you can wait for it to finish before the function returns, you need to find a suspending alternative to `kafkaSender.sendAsync()`.

Comment: But I’m not sure how that relates to mocking and testing. But in production, that’s how it would behave.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand correctly, so please excuse me, but how does it matter? My problem is that the function before this one is called out of order, which should not be affected by what is in it? As in, even before I call KafkaSender.sendAsync(), the method it's in [publisher.changeState()] is called out of order. As I am mocking publisher with coEvery { publisher.publishChangeState(any()) } returns Unit , I am basically exchanging the code inside this function for mocked code. As such, KafkaSender should never be called and yet it produces errors?

Comment: I am aware Kafkasender.sendAsync() is asynchronous, that is correct behavior for passing messages along, my confusion is up to that point, it should act more or less synchronously in one coroutine. Sometimes it does, sometime it does not, and I would like to figure out why so i don't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: It can only act synchronously in a coroutine if you convert it to a proper suspending function using either `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. Otherwise, the coroutine has no awareness of it being an asynchronous function and has no way to wait for it. Maybe it sometimes seems synchronous simply because it executes quickly or takes approximately the same amount of time for each task so they finish roughly in the order you submit them.

Comment: That would then be a separate error on my part. I will fix that, thank you. I do not believe it will solve the problem here, however.